# Getting map item with reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to get a map value by its key using reflection:

```
HashMap<String, Float> myMap = new HashMap<String, Float>();
myMap.put("time", Float.valueOf(-1.7));
String param = "time";
//...
float modif = (float)myMap.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("get", String.class).invoke(myMap, param);
```

But I get this error notification:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.util.HashMap.get(java.lang.String)
```

Can anybody, please, suggest why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your providing wrong parameter type during call of DeclaredMethod funcion. It should be Object.class instead of String.class

```
getDeclaredMethod("get", Object.class)
```

The complete line in your example would be like -

```
Float modif = (Float) myMap.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("get", Object.class).invoke(myMap, param);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem here is the type of the argument of the `get` method, it is not `String` but `Object` as you can see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)), this will work:

```
float modif = (float)myMap.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("get", Object.class)
    .invoke(myMap, param);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your suggestion solved my problem but Naveen Ramawat gave his answer a bit earlier so I mark his one as accepted.